# Should I create APFS encrypted disk image on hard disk drives?

Tags: high-sierra, apfs

[image]

I'm about to create an encrypted sparse disk image on my HFS+ formatted hard drive, but then I wondered if APFS's drawbacks on HDDs will mean anything in this case, since the hardware is anyway on HFS+. Since the disk image is in software, I think APFS should do faster logical copying and decrypting because it's newer but I don't really know how this works.

Comment: apfs isn't recommended for HDDs.  Be sure to keep good backups should you encrypt the drive.

Answer (score 2):

It's more like the benefits/features of APFS won't mean anything. A lot of it takes advantage of the fact that random (arbitrary) locations can be read from a SSD with no "seek time" penalties you might get in an HDD

Creating a small disk image on a HDD *might* help disguise how much APFS slows down on a HDD if it's kept in one continuous piece, and the drive has a big cache, but 200GB image on a 1TB drive is only ever going to perform as well as the drive it's on minus overhead.